# Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a shiny app that finds the minimum or maximum of an equation. To maximise I simply want to use the negative of the equation and find its minimum. The function I'm using takes the input as a character. The as.character is giving me the following error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'.

UI:

```
library(shiny)
source("simulated_annealing.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simulated Annealing App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel("User input",
                 textInput("ObjectiveFun",
                           h3("Objective Function"),
                           value = "(x+2*y-7)^2+(2*x+y-5)^2"),
                 radioButtons("maxormin",
                              h3("Goal"),
                              choices=c("Minimise"=1, "Maximise"=2)),),
    mainPanel("System Outputs",
            textOutput("finalvalues")),
    ),
)
```

SERVER:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  
  output$finalvalues <- renderText({
   
    Func <- as.character(reactive({input$ObjectiveFn}))
    if(input$maxormin == 2)
    {
      Func <- paste(c("-(",Func,")"),sep="",collapse="",end="")
    }
    #the rest of the inputs to the function below seem to work so they are not included
    value <- simannealing(Func,temp,I,A,alpha,nepochs,xlower,xupper,ylower,yupper)
    finalvalues <- paste("Final value is:", value[3],"and x value: ", value[1], "and y value: ", value[2])
  })  
}
```

If I need to upload any of the other code please let me know

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow.  the line `as.character(reactive({input$ObjectiveFn}))` defines a function then tries to turn the function itself into a character, which doesn't work.  Instead you most likely want to change the output of the function to a character.

Answer (score 0):

`input$ObjectiveFn` is already reactive, so you don't need the `reactive` around it.